# Helping IDE resolve file paths in included files

Tags: php, ide, comments, include-path, phpstorm

I have a standard front controller / bootstrap configuration, with the front controller at `root/index.php` and the bootstrap at `root/app/bootstrap.php`.

The front controller loads the boostrap file with `require_once 'app/bootstrap.php';`.

The bootstrap then loads necessary files using paths relative to the front controller, such as `require_once 'model/model.php';`.

My IDE (PhpStorm 3.0.2) flags the file paths in the bootstrap with a warning that says "Can't resolve target of expression..."

Is there a comment and/or code that can I add to the bootstrap file to help my IDE recognize and resolve the directory/inclusion scheme?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following ought to work. Annoyingly, it doesn't work if you use $config->directoryroot, but there's a bug open about that [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-7738) so it should work itself out in future builds.

```
$directoryroot = '/full/system/path/to/docroot';

require_once($directoryroot.'/app/bootstrap.php');
```

Comment: Thanks - glad to know about the bug report. My concern with providing the full path each time is that this creates extra work for PHP to do. It's very little extra work, I know, but I think I'd rather live with the ugly warning than the extra code. Have you ever found an IDE smart enough to figure this out on its own?

Comment: @cantera25 "this creates extra work for PHP to do" ??? Providing full path for include/require is actually faster than relative paths, as file gets processed straight away (one 1st iteration) with no need for checking relative paths (which will be counted as at least 2nd iteration). Although the time difference is very small.

Comment: You can also use `__DIR__` constant (which is relevant to the current file) or `dirname(__FILE__)` (for lower PHP versions compatibility).

Comment: Good - I'm glad I was wrong about this. It seemed logical that it would be more work to look up the value of a constant/variable than make a "direct trip" from the current path. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I find that my logic/instincts about this type of thing is usually wrong. Where does one go to properly learn a nuance of the language like this (besides here of course)?

Comment: The comments on the php.net manual pages are a wealth of information if you have the time to read through them.